# SQL Select Error When using Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CASE WHEN PFW_Access__c = 1
    THEN 'New Employee (' + New_Employee_Name__c + ') needs PFW Access'
    ELSE ''
END AS PFWAccessDesc,`
```

The line above is just one of many lines in my select statement. It outputs correctly with `New Employee (name) needs PFW Access`.  What I'm trying to do is to add another field to the output `Description_Short__c` but when I tried to add it to the statement I receive an error.  I'm not sure how to add it in to the statement to show in the output.

Comment: 1) Show the whole query; 2) What flavor of SQL is this; 3) What error are you getting

Comment: I am inferring from your other questions this is SQL Server, so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah, the infamous "an error". If only the people writing software such as SQL Server would include useful information in error messages</sarcasm>

Comment: You have a tick mark after the comma at the end of the column...

Comment: did you get this solved? if not, you should add a comment or edit your question with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

is this waht you are after?

```
CASE WHEN PFW_Access__c = 1
    THEN 'New Employee (' + ISNULL(New_Employee_Name__c,'') + ') needs PFW Access '
        +ISNULL(Description_Short__c,'')
    ELSE ''
END AS PFWAccessDesc,
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly from a previous question, Description_Short__c is a text field in your database. If you're trying to do just about anything w/ this column, you're going to have to use `cast(Description_Short__c as varchar(max))` instead of `Description_Short__c`.

Comment: This begs the question, why is a column called Description_*Short*__c stored in a `TEXT` column? Do they need a dump truck to store the *Long* description?